# Postgres Some sort of Joining?

Tags: postgresql, join, subquery

I am pretty new to postgres and having troubles with something pretty difficult, which I need pretty badly. Additionally I am not working in a proper editor, it's some form of webbased editor. Please consider that.

Here my Query:

```
select coalesce('user') as user_src,
       coalesce(root_domain(hostname), hostname, 'unknown') as web_domain,
       count (*) as nohits
from $log
where coalesce(root_domain(hostname), hostname, 'unknown') in
    (select coalesce(root_domain(hostname), hostname, 'unknown') as web_domain
          from $log
          group by web_domain
          limit 10
    ) 
group by user_src, web_domain
order by user_src, web_domain, nohits desc
```

But the results don't look how i want them to look.
I would like to have ALL the Users + their top 10 websites.
Now i see All the Users and a **total** of 10 websites, split to all Users. -> some user then just have 0, because they never visited one of those top 10.

Thx for looking into it!

Edit: Thats how i transformed it (not working - this error: ERROR:  column "hostname" does not exist)

```
select  coalesce('user') as user_src,
        coalesce(root_domain(hostname), hostname, 'unknown') as web_domain,
        count (*) as nohits
from
    (select coalesce('user') as user_src,
            coalesce(root_domain(hostname), hostname, 'unknown') as web_domain,
            count (*) as nohits,
            rank() over (partition by coalesce('user') order by coalesce('user'), count (*) desc) as rank
    from $log
    group by user_src, web_domain) w
where rank <= 2
order by user_src, rank
```

That would work eg.: (just to make sure 'hostname' exists)

```
select  coalesce('user') as user_src,
        coalesce(root_domain(hostname), hostname, 'unknown') as web_domain,
        count (*) as nohits
from $log
group by user_src, web_domain
order by user_src, nohits
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query as you post it cannot show a breakdown by "user", as the "coalesce('user')" part is a single entity. What would work well for you is one of PostgreSQL's [Window Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html). I will demonstrate a simple example of using RANK(), to get the top N for specific users.

```
begin;

drop table if exists weblog;
create table weblog (
"user"    int,
url     text
);

insert into weblog values
(1,'http://www.1.com'),
(1,'http://www.1.com'),
(1,'http://www.2.com'),
(1,'http://www.2.com'),
(1,'http://www.3.com'),
(1,'http://www.4.com'),
(1,'http://www.5.com'),
(1,'http://www.6.com'),

(2,'http://www.2.com'),
(2,'http://www.2.com'),
(2,'http://www.3.com'),
(2,'http://www.4.com'),
(2,'http://www.4.com'),
(2,'http://www.4.com'),
(2,'http://www.5.com'),
(2,'http://www.6.com');


select  "user",
        url,
        hits,
        rank
from    (select "user",
                url,
                count(*) as hits,
                rank() over (partition by "user" order by count(*) desc,url) as rank
        from weblog
        group by "user",url) w
where rank <= 2
order by "user",rank;

 user |       url        | hits | rank 
------+------------------+------+------
    1 | http://www.1.com |    2 |    1
    1 | http://www.2.com |    2 |    2
    2 | http://www.4.com |    3 |    1
    2 | http://www.2.com |    2 |    2


rollback;
```

Hopefully that is useful to you.

---

[after OP edited answer:]

Your outer query should just be pulling the columns from the inner query, not redoing the same steps. Try the following (from your most recent edit)

```
select  user_src,
        web_domain,
        nohits
from
    (select coalesce('user') as user_src,
            coalesce(root_domain(hostname), hostname, 'unknown') as web_domain,
            count (*) as nohits,
            rank() over (partition by coalesce('user') order by coalesce('user'), count (*) desc) as rank
    from $log
    group by user_src, web_domain) w
where rank <= 2
order by user_src, rank
```

Comment: I have a Question about that; is that a temporary table? Because I have no permissions to change the database itself. thx for the info, I will test it as soon as possible.

Comment: The "weblog" table I created above was simply to demonstrate a Window function over a real table. I didn't have your table's structure or test data, so I quickly fabricated some for testing.

Comment: Maybe I am confused, but I don't get how your Query would reduce the amount of domains per user. + I have no such a thing as "rank". and i can't work on the table. It's static, i can just query it. I am "creating" the rank by combining hits with domain. and put them on descending. the aim would still be to query ALL the users and only the limited amount of 10 Domains PER user

Comment: "rank()" is calculated on the fly -- it is not writing anything to the db. The "where rank <= 2" section in the outer query is limiting the results to the top 2 *per* user.
From the "Window Functions" link in my original reply: "A window function performs a calculation across a set of table rows that are somehow related to the current row. This is comparable to the type of calculation that can be done with an aggregate function."

Comment: I get it now, it looks good, even though i am now having troubles with this line: coalesce(root_domain(hostname), hostname, 'unknown') as web_domain                      in my previous query it worked fine, now it tells me, that hostname does not exist in my db. I am very confused. Good thing though, your query doesn't throw me any error, i am one step further now. thanks a lot for that. maybe you have a clue about this error now?                       ERROR:  column "hostname" does not exist

Comment: Show your updated query, we should be able to determine the problem by looking at it.

Comment: @XXInvidiaXX I've updated my answer to reflect your most recent changes to your query. See if the updated version works for you.

Comment: You my dear, saved my day! Thank you very much! I would upvote, but I can't yet! - but i am not forgetting :)